# R Colorize departments of a france map according to the values of a vector

Tags: r, colors, maps

Hi how can i do a map like that with R?
[image]

The code that gives this map but i dont have the data :

```
 library(RColorBrewer)
 library(classInt)
 library(maptools)
 plotvar <- fecondite$fecond1524
 nclr <- 4
 plotclr <- brewer.pal(nclr,"PuOr")
 plotclr <- plotclr[nclr:1] # r´eordonne les couleurs
 class <- classIntervals(plotvar, nclr, style="equal")
 colcode <- findColours(class, plotclr)
 plot(departements,col=colcode)
 locator(n=1) #sert `a trouver les coordonn´ees
 du point o`u vous souhaitez placer la l´egende
 legend(166963,6561753,legend=names(attr(colcode,"table")),
 fill=attr(colcode, "palette"), cex=0.6, bty="n")
```

In fact i want to know : for example with a vector that contains numbers from 1 to 1000 that are relate to the departements how to assign differents color for each intervals [1 , 100] , [100, 500] , [500 , 1000 ] ?

Comment: do you have any example code?

Comment: I just have the code that give this map but i dont have the data so i cant use this code to test it

Comment: and you want random coloring?

Comment: No i dont want random coloring i want to colorize by the value of a vector for example a vector that contains the superficy of each departments with a legend similar to the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
library(raster)

fr <- getData(country='France',level=2)
#plot(fr)

# random terrain colors
fr$col <- terrain.colors(256)[floor(runif(length(fr),0,255))]

# less random
#fr$col <- terrain.colors(length(fr))

plot(fr,col=fr$col)
```

#### Edit:

You can access the Department names under `fr$NAME_2` and then assign your colors accordingly:

```
color_df <- data.frame(Dep=fr$NAME_2,color=sample(colors(distinct=T),length(fr),replace = F))

fr$col <- color_df$color

plot(fr,col=fr$col)

print(color_df)
```

This example is a bit silly, since it's again random colors. But you could assign a gradient or any other color value you want to each Department.

#### Edit 2: Highlight single Department

```
library(raster)

fr <- getData(country='France',level=2)

fr$col[fr$NAME_2 == 'Hautes-Alpes'] <- 'red'

plot(fr,col=fr$col)
```

#### Edit 3: Plot by fake fertility groups

```
library(raster)

fr <- getData(country='France',level=2)

# fertility classes
classes <- c('0-1.4','1.4-2.4','2.5-3')

#fake data
fr$fertility <- sample(seq(1,3,0.1),length(fr),replace = T)

# assign groups
fr$fertgroups <- round(fr$fertility) 

# assign corresponding colors (red = low, yellow = mid, green = high)
fr$cols <- c('red','yellow','green')[fr$fertgroups]

#plot
plot(fr,col=fr$cols)
```

Or with 4 classes:

```
library(raster)

fr <- getData(country='France',level=2)

classes <- c('0-1','1-1.5','1.5-2','2-3')

fr$fertility <- sample(seq(1,3,0.1),length(fr),replace = T)

fr$fertgroups[fr$fertility <=1] <-1 
fr$fertgroups[fr$fertility > 1 & fr$fertility <=1.5] <-2 
fr$fertgroups[fr$fertility > 1.5 & fr$fertility <=2] <-3 
fr$fertgroups[fr$fertility > 2 & fr$fertility <=3] <- 4 

fr$cols <- c('red','orange','yellow','green')[fr$fertgroups]

plot(fr,col=fr$cols)
```

Comment: No sorry your code gives me a map with no colors at all

Comment: yeah that works^^ sorry my bad in fact i dont want random coloring i want to colorize by the value of a vector for example a vector that contains the superficy of each departments with a legend similar to the picture.

Comment: See my edit ... It really depends which colors you want. But since you have already the Department names inside the `fr` object, you can use any color scheme you like

Comment: Thanks ;) can you show me a example with a gradient assign to a single department please?

Comment: you mean one department colored, the rest white?

Comment: yes ^^ and with a vector that contains numbers from 1 to 1000 that are relate to the departements how to assign differents color for each intervals [1 , 100] , [100, 500] , [500 , 1000 ] for example?

Comment: That's already specific, you should have put that in your question ;)

Comment: Yeah sorry i was not very clear^^ i really dont know from what you showed me how to do something that looks like the picture above^^.

Comment: Ok, there should be a reasoning behind your coloring. What are the numbers in the interval? Because, it would be easy to randomly split the departments into 3 groups and assign them a color ...

Comment: The numbers in the pictures are about fecundity of young women in france that comes from the website insee.But i can't find the data.

Comment: Ok, and you want to group them in 3 groups? I don't have the variable, but I can try to simulate it

Comment: Thanks i think its what i want ;) how to add a legend?Sorry for my english im french ^^

Comment: you should look at the `legend` function, either from the R base plotting or from the `maptools` package, which was used in your example code. Basically you need to give position, labels and colors. It's a bit fiddling around to find the exact position you want. Be aware since it's spatial data, `x` and `y` position of the legend will be in LON LAT coordinates